# Opening a new window using tkinter button

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

As you can see on my code I'm trying to open a new window with a button. Window opens but welcome message isn't showing like the way that I want.

It shows Welcome PY_VAR0 PY_VAR1. But I would like to show a name.

I've tried using return command to return variables from `getvalue()` function but it doesn't work.

```
def getvalue():
    name.get()
    surname.get()

def newwindow():
    window.destroy()
    window2 = tk.Tk()
    label3 = tk.Label(text="Welcome {} {}".format(name,surname)).grid()
    window2.mainloop()


button = tk.Button(window,text="Submit",command=getvalue and newwindow).grid(row=3,column=1)

window.mainloop()
```

I would like to open a new window with a welcome message.

Comment: Where are your `name` and `surname` variables defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `.get()` to get value from `StringVar`, `IntVar`, etc - `name.get()`, `surname.get()`

```
label3 = tk.Label(text="Welcome {} {}".format(name.get(), surname.get()))
label3.grid()
```

And remeber: To set value you will have to use `variable.set(value)` instead of `variable = value`

BTW: you have big mistake in this line (and others)

```
label3 = tk.Label(..).grid(..)
```

It assign `None` to `label3` because `grid()/pack()/place()` return `None`

You have to do it in two steps

```
label3 = tk.Label(..)
label3.grid(..)
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you `print(name + " " + surname)`?

If those variables have the correct values maybe you should try rewriting your script a couple different ways, for example:

```
labelText = "Welcome " + name + " " + surname
label3 = tk.Label(text=labelText)
```

Comment: It says TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "StringVar") to str.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `messagebox` to open a new window as well as print a welcome message. it is really simple.

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button

# Make sure to import messagebox like this, otherwise you might get issues
import tkinter.messagebox

def messagebox():
    tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('title','Welcome!')

def main():

    width, height = 500, 500

    root = Tk()
    root.geometry(f'{width}x{height}')
    root.title('My window')

    button = Button(root, width=150, height=70, command=messagebox)
    button.pack()

    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Please `import messagebox` the way it is shown, I am not sure why but `tkinter` does not like other ways.